# Issues using tensorflow inside conda jupyter lab notebook

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conda

I've been running into issue trying to setup a jupyter lab that is able to use tensorflow and keras.

tl;dr I've tried a multitude of different ways of installing it in a virtual env on conda using cmd(I'm on windows) as well as using the GUI to install it. In all cases i'm able to import tensorflow into python, but then when I open the jupyter lab notebook in browser, it can never find the module.

Long version:
Open Anconda and launch cmd in the base env.
cd to where I want to setup the environment, basically inside a whole bunch of subdirectories inside OneDrive as that's what I use for college.

`(base) C:\Users\adamp>cd Onedrive - maynooth university/year 4/cs401/assignments/ass2`

Create the conda virtual env: `conda create -n cs401_ass2 --yes`

And then activate it using: `conda activate cs401_ass2`

So now I'm inside the venv.

Install tensorflow using `conda install tensorflow`

Accept all the packages etc...

Now its installed I can check it using python. Type `python`

Then `import tensorflow as tf`

And it throws up no errors so as I understand that means that it installed correctly....

So now I exit out of python which returns me to my virtual env. Then I want to boot jupyter lab which I do by typing `jupyter lab`

It opens in my browser (chrome)

I open a fresh iPy notebook

Type `import tensorflow as tf` and now it returns that it doesn't have the module...

Error message ==>  https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLFTP.png

Help me Obiwan....you're my only hope

Comment: Welcome to the SO! In future please don't paste images with errors or code, just copy the code and use formatting. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not installed `jupyter-lab` to this environment, so Windows takes the next-best thing: another JupyterLab that it has on its PATH. Trouble is, in that environment `tensorflow` is not installed - hence the error.

Solution:

- Activate the env: `conda activate cs401_ass2`
- Install JupyterLab: `conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab`

Yours truly, Obiwan.